# How to access webdav files in the codebase in BigCommerce?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bigcommerce

I have `.js` and `.json` files in webdav and I'm able to access them using cyberduck, however I'd like to import them in the codebase like this:

```
import File from "webdave/products/somefile";
```

I found a js package that I think will allow me to do that called [webdav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav) however I'm getting cors error when connecting to the client, and upon searching I discovered that [BigCommerce](https://www.bigcommerce.com/) does [not allow api call to the store database?](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00004p4fc2SAA/blocked-by-cors-policy?language=en_US)

Is there a way around it? basically I will be storing js files in webdav containing js objects for some product configurations, so I need those js objects in the codebase.

Comment: The question is unclear. BigCommerce lists many partner sites, like Netlify, where you could host your app and store css and js files.  Please focus your question on a single problem and show any code you have written.

Comment: I want to access files (.js) that are stored in webdav in the codebase, and not by using something like cyberduck. That way I can import them like a js file stored locally, ex: import myFileStoredInWebdav from "webdav/file.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the files with an AJAX request, and use its contents within the success.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/content/filname.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success(data) { 
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: by using /content endpoint, will that automatically fetch from the content folder in webdav? also can I use axios?

Comment: You should only be putting files in the content folder in WebDAV (or subfolders in content). And yes, this will tie into that folder. I have not used Axios here, but I'd imagine it should be fine.